# What were Adi Shankaracharya's views on Samhita(ritualistic part of the Vedas)?

Tags: vedas, adi-shankaracharya

What were Adi Shankaracharya's views on Samhita(ritualistic part of the Vedas)?

Did he believe that Samhita are equal to upanishad and are authoritative and eternal?

And should/can one follow the Samhita part of the Vedas?

Comment: Some Upanishads are themselves complete Samhitas (like Isha Upanishad)... other major Upanishads too cite verses from Samhitas frequently... Adi Shankara in his Brahma Sutra Bhasya quotes some Samhitas mantras from Rigveda (like 'yathA purvama kalpayet')..